# Number of files generated by a Spark Job

Tags: apache-spark

I want to monitor the number of files that spark generates, and maybe raise an exception if it is generating a lot of files. Is there any way to see this?

Answer (score 0):

well it depends on how you are doing the write operation. Assuming you are writing the content of a dataframe or rdd as output, the easiest way would be to see number of partitions in your final dataframe/rdd. Basically each partition is written as a separate file.

Assuming you are using scala, this should give you the number of partitions.

```
df.rdd.getNumPartitions
```

Instead of raising an exception and causing job to fail, i would suggest that you use coalesce function to repartition the df with a value that suits you need. For example, if the output is not too large (1 Gb or less) i use coalesce(1) and write only 1 file.

Comment: What happens if the number of records have are less than the number of partitions? How many files will be created than? say 10 rows 20 partition

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Logically a partition is a group of records so partition without any records cannot exist. Do you have a sample code where you generated such a dataframe.